# Strange behaviour with loading entity by attribute

Tags: catalog, eav, ee-1.13.0.1

Maybe I'm missing something fundamental by how can it be that the following code works fine and finds an entity:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->loadByAttribute('url_key', $urlKeyToCheck);
```

And the following is not:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$model->loadByAttribute('url_key', $urlKeyToCheck);
```

Comment: So did that answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`loadByAttribute` returns an object, not related to the current model instance:

```
public function loadByAttribute($attribute, $value, $additionalAttributes = '*')
{
    $collection = $this->getResourceCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect($additionalAttributes)
        ->addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $value)
        ->setPage(1,1);

    foreach ($collection as $object) {
        return $object;
    }
    return false;
}
```

`loadByAttribute` does not work like `load`.
`load` changes the current model instance, `loadByAttribute` doesn't. It just returns the first object in the collection that has a specified value for a certain attribute.